# ssis - I have to run each task manually

Tags: sql, ssis, execution

I am just starting on SSIS and created a simple package to start off with. I ran the import/export wizard from SSDT  where I am copying table contents from a table to an excel spreadsheet. I eventually get the table contents on the spreadsheet but I have to run the Execute SQL task first, then run the Data Flow task second manually. Not sure why the data Flow task does not pick up after the Execute SQL task completes. The connection is set to run on success. I googled the heck out of this and cannot find an answer. I am running Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated) version 12.0.21005.   Any answer (or clue) would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[image: Control Flow]

[image: Data Flow]

Comment: paste screenshot of your ssis flow

Comment: When you click the play button and the first thing runs but not the connected, find your Output window and copy paste all the text in there into your question. I suspect there's something hiding in there that will help identify why the successor tasks are not firing.

Comment: Thank you BillInKC

Here is the output:

SSIS package "C:\Users\bsmith\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\projects\Integration Services Project7\Integration Services Project7\Package1.dtsx" starting.
SSIS package "C:\Users\bsmith\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\projects\Integration Services Project7\Integration Services Project7\Package1.dtsx" finished: Success.
The program '[10112] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Eshirvana - screenshots posted above, thank you!

Comment: @BillSmith please go to *Execution Results* and take a screenshot.

Comment: @BillSmith how are you running the package? do you click on the Start button? or do you right click on the first task and click Execute Task? because if the latter, it is meant to run only one task at a time.

Comment: Jayvee - thank you, that was the issue. Thank you everyone who responded